# How to edit/change SHA1 certificate in Google Play Console?

Tags: certificate, google-play-services, sha1, google-play-console, google-console-developer

I want to replace the SHA-1 certificate fingerprint number (A) with the SHA-1 certificate fingerprint number (B) in the Google Play Console. How can I do that or edit/delete the one I want to replace?

[image: explanation image]

I already tried to upload a new version build but that didn't let me change the SHA-1.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot do that. The certificate used to sign an application cannot be changed. That's because your app could not be updated on your users devices if you did so. Either whitelist this App Signing certificate on all APIs you are using so that your app works with it, or you'll have to delete the app and recreate it, decline enrolling in App Signing initially, then enroll later if you wish to create a separate upload key.